# Can't login as root via SSH after adding another user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Login via SSH worked fine for a long time until i add another user and enable password authorization (it was public key only). Now I can't login as root neither with password or public key. But I'm sure for a 100% about my credentials, because I able to switch to root with `su` and password from new added user session.

Have you any ideas how to bring root login back? Thanks

Server OS verion Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PermitRootLogin no
#StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 3
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server


GatewayPorts=clientspecified
#PasswordAuthentication no

#Match address 10.1.0.0/24
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

`ssh -vvv`

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:x1v7USU6qhcSxkVnnYVab+8r8oC0vNPewT4glgxJ6Nc agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:x1v7USU6qhcSxkVnnYVab+8r8oC0vNPewT4glgxJ6Nc agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:x1v7USU6qhcSxkVnnYVab+8r8oC0vNPewT4glgxJ6Nc
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:x1v7USU6qhcSxkVnnYVab+8r8oC0vNPewT4glgxJ6Nc
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/dimka/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Please tell me you at least suspect `PermitRootLogin no` has something to do with root login not being permitted. Have you tried to investigate this option?

Comment: Can you post your entire `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? The provided text does not contain the line that allows public key authentication, despite the server being configured to allow that. This makes me wonder if you are looking at the correct configuration file.  You also have `PasswordAuthentication yes` listed twice

Comment: @Ramhound The default for `PubkeyAuthentication` is `yes` (at least [in OpenSSH](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PubkeyAuthentication)).

Comment: @Ramhound I've posted all lines from config except comments

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski this options was `no` all the time i worked with this server. It is may permit login as root of course, but it shouldn't now because of value `no`.

Comment: @Dim_K - Can you post everything, including comments?  I don't trust the current state of your configuration file, since you indicate something was working, now it's not working. Plus I still think it's odd that "PasswordAuthentication yes" is listed twice.

Comment: @Ramhound updated post a moment ago

Comment: *PermitRootLogin no* is the reason you cannot SSH as root.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes man, you are right. I don't know why is `no` value evaluated this way. Please add your answer i will mark it is as correct. And thanks a lot again